# Floating point exception when trying to connect to MySQL using pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, centos, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL database using `pyodbc`.

```
import pyodbc
cxn_str = (
    'DRIVER=MySQL;'
    'SERVER=192.168.56.121;'
    'DATABASE=customer_data;'
    'UID=xxxxx;'
    'PWD=xxxxx;'
    'CHARSET=utf8mb4;' 
    )
pyodbc.connect(cxn_str)
```

The output I receive is: 
`Floating point exception`

How can I solve this error?

I have ensured that the MySQL database is remotely accessible.

Environment:

- Operating System: `CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`
- Kernel: `Linux 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64`
- Architecture: `x86-64`
- Output of `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue on a clean install of Centos 7 (Core). Does the error occur immediately upon executing the `pyodbc.connect` method?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, it displays the message "Floating point exception" and exits the script.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/81

Comment: What version of MySQL Server are you trying to hit? Mine is "5.6.13 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)".

Comment: @GordThompson Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: @GordThompson Can you briefly list the steps you did to install the driver?

Comment: I opened the "Software" app, searched for "odbc", ticked the box beside "ODBC Driver for MySQL", and clicked the "Apply Changes" button.